# CXF - Method name contains target namespace prefix

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a client application to consume SOAP WS. The project is using maven, Spring and CXF 3.1.12 for the WS consuming part.

I have the same project in Eclipse as well as in IntelliJ Community. I execute mvn clean package on in both cases, files are generated automatically to support the WS consuming. Classes are being generated using wsdl2java and WSDL files are contained locally.

When I execute a test case in eclipse I have the following SOAP XML message being sent (which works correctly).

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ListContent xmlns="http://uri.seeburger.com/seefx/fileTransfer/3">
        <FullPath>/My Files/</FullPath>
        <IncludeDirectories>true</IncludeDirectories>
        <IncludePending>true</IncludePending>
    </ListContent>
</soap:Body>
```

When I execute the same test case in IntelliJ I have the following SOAP XML message sent (which fails during unmarshalling on the server side):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:ListContent xmlns:ns2="http://uri.seeburger.com/seefx/fileTransfer/3">
        <FullPath>/My Files/</FullPath>
        <IncludeDirectories>true</IncludeDirectories>
        <IncludePending>true</IncludePending>
    </ns2:ListContent>
</soap:Body>
```

I am unable to understand who/what/why is adding the **ns2** in the produced XML.

The test case is the same from the same source which is checked out from SVN to both IDEs. When the test case is executed in eclipse it produces a different XML message than that produced when the test case is executed in IntelliJ.

What has currently worked in all environments is placing the generated classes under the default `src/main/java` path.

Comment: Why would the test case differ on each IDE? What are you really doing here? What do you mean by test?

Comment: The test case is the same from the same source which is checked out from SVN to both IDEs. When the test case is executed in eclipse it produces a different XML message than that produced when the test case is executed in IntelliJ.

Comment: What happens when you execute the tests from the cli, using maven?  
And, can you confirm that both IDEs, and the cli, all point to the same version of java and maven?

Comment: I can confirm that same maven and jdk are being used. I have not yet run the tests from cli. I will try as soon as possible and get back. What has currently worked in all environments is placing the generated classes under the default src/main/java path.

Comment: Where are the generated files created by maven -- somewhere like target/generated-sources/cxf? Have you told IntelliJ or eclipse about that directory?